# Access XBAP function

Tags: wpf, save, mdi, xbap

I have written a XBAP application which runs on iis at the moment.  Now I have a requirement to create a new MDI application which can host multiple xbap applications.  I have created this by including a web browser control in each mdi child and it works.

I now have a new reuirement (The challenge) which is to save the configuration configuration i.e selected items in dropdowns and text entered in each xbap (shown in web browser which is a part of mdi child which is a child of mdi parent).  to a single xml file.  The save button will be present in MDI parent. Hope I have explained it well.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks